# Is it possible to save variable values when using pairs?

Tags: r

Is it possible to do something like this somehow with pairs or a similar function?

```
var = "" #initialization
panel.pearson <- function(x, y, ...) {
    horizontal <- (par("usr")[1] + par("usr")[2]) / 2; 
    vertical <- (par("usr")[3] + par("usr")[4]) / 2;
    cor = cor.test(x,y)
    cor.p = cor$p.value
    cor.r = cor$estimate
    cor.p = round(cor.p, digits = 2)
    cor.r = round(cor.r, digits = 2)
    stars = ifelse(cor.p < .001, "***", ifelse(cor.p < .01, "** ", ifelse(cor.p < .05, "* ", " ")))
    format_r_p = paste(cor.r, stars, sep="")
    text(horizontal, vertical, format_r_p, cex=2)
    var = c(var, format_r_p)
}
pairs(crime, upper.panel=panel.pearson )
```

`var` would output all the `format_r_p` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s possible but it’s a really, really bad idea in general: functions should not mutate global state.

So instead, isolate the modification to be local instead of global:

```
var = ''
pairs(crime, upper.panel = function (x, y, ...) {
    result = panel.pearson(x, y, ...)
    var <<- c(var, result)
    result
})
```

Now, instead of making `panel.pearson` modify any global magic variables, we use an anonymous function *in the scope* of the call to `pairs` to modify a variable *in the scope* of the call to `pairs`, i.e. locally.

To modify this variable from inside the anonymous function, we use `<<-` instead of the normal assignment.

Comment: I know it's a bad idea. It's for a small homework assignment. Visual data for collinearity would be enough, but I want to automate it.